# MySql Does Not Respond

Tags: mysql, cygwin, easyphp

possibly same issue as
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,408161,408181#msg-408181

```
$ ./mysql -u root -proot --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
> show databases;
[WAIT FOREVER AND NOTHING EVER HAPPENS]
> exit;
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exit' at line 1
[uhhhhhhhh what?]
Database
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
phpmyadmin
temp
othertables
[!?!]


$ ./mysql -u root -proot --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
> UPDATE blah blah blah;
[NOTHING EVER]
exit;
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exit' at line 1
[SO DID IT WORK????!!!!!!! WHAT THE!!!!!]

$ ./mysql -u root -proot --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
> select * from blah blah blah
[NOTHING EVER]
> exit;
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'exit' at line 1
[UHHH so did it select zero lines???? one two.....   !!!!!!!]
```

so sometimes it responds... but only when you don't really care what the response is and only after mysql decides to spontaneously combust...............

PHP couldn't be compiled on my system so I am now using EasyPHP (which I assume is irrelevant).

Any ideas... it's as if though mysql can't communicate with my console correctly... does mysql use non-standard terminal emulation???? it works fine on a CentOS server.

The commands appear to work, however not having a direct line of sight to the actual contents of the database is a MASSIVE hindrance to ANY debugging issues.

Comment: What do MySQL command line problems have to do with PHP? that being said, without seeing an actual console level output and understanding what you are doing, I am not clear on what your problem is. Can you copy/paste EXACT console input output without various commentary.

Comment: since it's locahost, you can safely omit specifying protocol and host. Just to save you a bit of time

Comment: sorry bad formatting, just changed it so the console output was clearer

Comment: In the last two cases. It seems you haven't issue any use * command to select your database before querying.

Comment: @MikeBrant thank you, but it still requires that I 'exit' before I can see any results... and even then errors are out of sync with the output of correct commands

Comment: Are those really your prompts - `>` instead of `mysql>`? Those are not the standard prompts.

Comment: @MikeBrant there are no prompts of anykind not even '> '.  is EasyPhp spy ware? :-)

Comment: @user3338098 Again. Can you post the EXACT input/output you are seeing?

Comment: $ ./mysql -u root -proot<br/>
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.<br/>
use db;<br/>
select * from aTable;<br/>
select * from fakeTable;<br/>
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 3: Table 'db.fakeTable' doesn't exist<br/>
col1    col2<br/>
1       text<br/>
2       text

Comment: @MikeBrant EasyPhp includes mysql... fyi that's why I brought it up.

Comment: mysql also doesn't handle keyboard navigation well, which is why I mentioned console terminal emulation... it's as if it can't understand the keyboard encoding for some keys (all my other (cygwin) console programs work fine though)

Comment: which led me to the solution... thanks! everything behaves as expected when run through the Windows Command Prompt (even 'mysql>' shows!)

Comment: Interesting. Glad you found a solution.  It did seem fishy with regards to the prompts you were getting and such. Added CYGWIN tag to this question since that seemed to be the root issue.

Comment: Please clean up your question. Try to remember this isn't a forum, and your question is meant to be a *work of reference* for future programmers with the same problem. Also, one or zero question marks and exclamation marks, not an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is almost completely incompatible with Cygwin's console.

I don't know who is at fault for using non-standard terminal behavior... (but I tend to assume MySql is at fault given that it should only be basic input and output, and most other native programs work well enough)

In order to use native MySQL on Windows you MUST use the windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Installing mysql client package for cygwin solves my problem.